# PhpStorm disable watching for vendor git repositories

Tags: php, git, composer-php, phpstorm

I am using git and PhpStorm for my project. When i trying to push, or pull, or to do any else action, i also see git repositories from `/vendor` (composer).

[image: Push window]

[image]

How to disable they for PhpStorm?

UPDATE:

`/vendor` already in `.gitignore`

```
# composer vendor dir
/vendor
```

Comment: Have you added `vendor/` to your `.gitignore`?

Comment: @jrenk Yes, i have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the solution! It was in `File->Settings->Version Control`. I Just unregister vendor roots. Thank all for help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the root of your project just create/edit the .gitignore file and add the following

```
/vendor
```

You can do this for any directory you would like

if you want to include a sub-directory of a directory you exclude just add something like this.

```
!/vendor/bin
```

Here are the relevant git docs about it:
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Edit: I saw you did indeed have a correct .gitignore [assumption based on your reaction to the comment] If you have already worked with a file in phpstorm and added it to the ignore pattern later phpstorm does nothing with it, you should be manually removing the folder from your machine and from the repo [by deleting and commiting/pushing].

Just delete it and commit it to origin. and just use composer to reinstall. voila!

Comment: Can i just delete `/vendor`, and then run `composer install` for this?

Comment: as long as your composer.json and composer.lock are still correct, yes

Comment: but the commit to origin part is actually important, that is the whole point of this right? so you dont have to pull/push the entire vendor directory and can just run composer.

Comment: Did it and reload PhpStorm. `vendor` repositories still there

Comment: Is the vendor directory still on the remote or local git repo?

Comment: nope.  .gitignore is .phpstormIgnored in this case.  See @Egretos's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know if very correctly applicable, but my search leading to this question was solved by applying "git reset" command on files I added prior adding them to a .gitignore file.

Comment: perhaps alternative: git rm -r --cached .

Comment: Plus other windows wth the same projects can't be opened ```cd .idea && git rm -r --cached *.*``` , ```cd .idea && git reset -- *.*```